# How to use expression (SpEL) in eclipse link @Query annotation?

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink, spring-data

How can I add conditional where clause in JPA query inside @Query method of Spring Data JPA repository method?

For Example,

```
@Query("select student from Student student #{:rollNumber == '123' ? 'where student.rollNumber > 123' : ''} ")
List<Student> findStudents(@Param("rollNumber") int rollNumber)
```

I am getting following exception :-

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select student from Student student #{:rollNumber == '123' ? 'where student.rollNumber > 123' : ''} ]. 
[62, 63] The FROM clause has 'Student student' and '#{:rollNumber =' that are not separated by a comma.
[104, 105] The identification variable '=' cannot be a reserved word.
[105, 172] The query contains a malformed ending.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1603)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: You need to use `?1` to inject `rollNumber` into the query.

Comment: ?1 or :paramName are one and the same thing. Spring supports named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if spring data currently injects query params to SpeL parser.
You could try something like this:

```
@Query("select student from Student student where :rollNumber==123 or student.rollNumber > 123 ")
List<Student> findStudents(@Param("rollNumber") int rollNumber)
```

Comment: This will never return me students with roll numbers < 123. I need the complete list when rollNumber is 123. (or any other condition with roll number)

Comment: It returms all students if you caal function with 123 as parameter. Little hack to compare just parameter and constant on first part of where clause. If parameter is anything else than 123 it gives you all students whose rollNumber > 123. Not very elegant solution tough.

Comment: it should be there after 1.7.2 - https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions